# aggregating when values appear in bidirectional order in data.frame in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have table where I have been able to use aggregate when both my columns had data in an (**A to B direction**) but I was wondering is there a way to aggregate or use dplyr when values in Column A and Column B appear bidirectionally.  For example values in column A and B in can appear in the follow directions (**A to B or B to A**).

```
library(data.table)
exampleset <-data.table(ColumnA = c("A2","A1","A3","A3","A4","A5"),
               ColumnB = c("A1","A2","A4","A3","A3","A5"),
               Colorcode = c("red","green","blue","yellow","red","red"))
```

Desired output:

```
output <- data.table(ColumnA =c("A1","A3","A3","A5"),
                     ColumnB=c("A2","A4","A3","A5"),
                     ColorcodeCount =c(2,2,1,1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific case, the best solution is likely, David Arenburg's using `pmin/pmax`:

```
exampleset[, .(Colorcode = uniqueN(Colorcode)), by = .(ColumnA = do.call(pmin, list(ColumnA, ColumnB)), 
                                                       ColumnB = do.call(pmax, list(ColumnA, ColumnB)))]
```

However, this isn't very generalizable to the case where you may want to order by 3 columns instead of 2.

---

Alternatively, my solution which uses `mapply` (updated from using `apply`) is:

You could create columns that have the same order always (so `A1\A2` will be treated the same as `A2/A1`) and then grouping by those unordered columns. Something like:

```
exampleset2 <- exampleset[,c("unorderA","unorderB") := data.frame(t(mapply(FUN = function(...) c(...)[order(c(...))], ColumnA, ColumnB, USE.NAMES = FALSE)))]
exampleset2[,list(ColorcodeCount = length(unique(Colorcode))), by = .(unorderA, unorderB)]

#   unorderA unorderB ColorcodeCount
#1:       A1       A2              2
#2:       A3       A4              2
#3:       A3       A3              1
#4:       A5       A5              1
```

On the other hand if you *really* wanted do it all in one call, another way would be:

```
exampleset[,list(ColorcodeCount = length(unique(Colorcode))), 
           by = .(t(mapply(FUN = function(...) c(...)[order(c(...))], ColumnA, ColumnB, USE.NAMES = FALSE))[,1],
                  t(mapply(FUN = function(...) c(...)[order(c(...))], ColumnA, ColumnB, USE.NAMES = FALSE))[,2])]

#    t t.1 ColorcodeCount
#1: A1  A2              2
#2: A3  A4              2
#3: A3  A3              1
#4: A5  A5              1
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  What did you do in that second by statement.

Comment: I grouped it by the first column from the `t(apply..` then by the second column. I'd recommend the first way since I think its cleaner, but it's up to you!

Comment: Awe I see, that did not even cross my mind.  I would be doing long for loops without your help on that.